# How to make SmartTouch application working in Nokia 5800 XpressMusic?

Tags: bluetooth, nokia

I have Nokia 5800 xpressMusic and after install SmartTouch application (PC Bluetooth remote control) it tells me that it is connected but not working. There a log file generated after running the server in PC contains the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.pyw", line 24, in run
  File "bluetooth\msbt.pyo", line 24, in **init**
IOError: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used.

Can anyone help me to make it working?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for this problems and it is as follows:
1- The problem appear when trying to open SmartTouch from my phone (TypeError("fall_max")) vanished after installing the latest version of python 1.9.7.

2- The second problem (takes a more time from me to figure it out and make it working) was a problem in Bluetooth stack. I have Toshiba satellite A200 with Toshiba Bluetooth stack, and SmartTouch works only with Microsoft Bluetooth stack. You can downlaod it from Toshiba web site and install it instead of Toshiba Bluetooth stack.